# I want to change the Wordpress comments file

Tags: posts, functions, comments, spam, comments-template

In the standard structure of Wordpress, a warning page appears when the user makes spam or goes too fast. The link structure of the warning page is "/wp-comments-post.php". Briefly (see images)
https://www.dropbox.com/s/b5icvg8cjzuc28q/wp-slow.png
https://www.dropbox.com/s/4yt8gdyl7hr1b0w/wp-spam.png

I want to link this link structure to a special page like "error" to hide it. Or, I just want to make a little warning window inside the page. How can we do that Thank you in advance!

Comment: Sounds like a case for Ajax to me.

Comment: I guess, no.  I went to the "wp-includes" folder.  I've edited the "comment-template.php" file.  ( I've edited the 2250 line )

`code` 'action'               => site_url( '/error.php' ), `code`

I pointed to "error.php". then I changed the name of "wp-comments-post.php" to "error.php" in the main directory.

Here is the result!  https://www.dropbox.com/s/84oy6u6067do6wp/error.php.png

I have not received an error on the site right now. everything is fine as needed. I will continue to monitor the result so that it does not cause an error.  @Nicolai

Comment: Don't edit core files, the changes will be overridden when you update WordPress.

Comment: Besides, it sounded like you want dynamic elements, hence the mentioning of Ajax, but maybe I misunderstood your intention.

Comment: Yeah. In fact, it makes more sense to change the link on the theme files. may not be a permanent solution. Thank you... (I'll try different ways)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the URL for the `action` of the comment form like this:

```
add_filter( 'comment_form_defaults', 'wpse316762_comment_form_defaults' );
function wpse316762_comment_form_defaults( $defaults ) {
  $defaults[ 'action' ] = site_url( '/error.php' );
  return $defaults;
}
```

Comment: A kernel file change can be overridden in updates. (Even if it does not cause any errors) Theme / Funcstion.Php is the definitive way to introduce. I just remembered. I will add the code and check. (I will restore the original file) 

Thank you very much!

Comment: I have restored the original "comment-template.php" file. and I added the code to the theme. This definitely worked. Thanks again.